# Functional force in raising a block upright

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here $5$ blocks of equal dimensions are placed one on another in two ways:
The $1^{st}$ way is by placing one upon another individually and the $2^{nd}$ is done by considering the $5$ blocks as one object and then making it upright. We have been asked to find which way is more favourable.

When I solved the question,I did it by calculating the work done in both processes. Obviously the work done in both processes were equal since they were the definition of work done using average displacement and using displacement of center of mass.

However the book did one more thing apart from that,they calculated the force needes in raising the blocks. That's the part where i am fuzzy. I didn't understand what they meant by average force(is that even a thing?) in the "$1^{st}$" step which is $\frac{mg(0+a+2a+3a+4a)}{10a}$. Secondly, I see they used integration for the second process without any details(how is a novice student supposed to figure all this out?). The division by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ also got over my head.

So, I request the physics lovers to kindly explain the concepts used in this problem since I never came across them till this date(NO NEED TO DO CALCULATIONS),I just need to understand what they basically did and what division by $10a$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ hold importance here.

Comment: What is the meaning of "functional force"?

Comment: I don't understand that as well,perhaps they meant average force.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? I mean the book title and author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't understand what they meant by average force(is that even a thing?) in the "1st" step which is $\frac{mg(0+a+2a+3a+4a)}{10a}$

By seeing the images you have provided the average force seems to be the total work done divided by the total displacement. Let's understand with an example:
Suppose you are moving $n$ bodies of mass $m_1$,$m_2$,$m_3$,...,$m_n$ by the distance $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,...,$x_n$ by force $F_1$,$F_2$,$F_3$,...,$F_n$ respectively then the average force will be $$F_{av} = \frac{F_1x_1 + F_2x_2 +F_3 x_3 + ... +F_nx_n}{x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n}$$ and same is in your case. Hope you can understand.

> Secondly i see they used integration for the second process without any details(how is a novice student supposed to figure all this out?). The division by $\frac{\pi}{2} $ also got over my head.

If you are not given any details then you need to obtain them and that's physics.
Suppose you have joined all the boxes then the mass of the body will be $5m$ and weight will be $5mg$ which will be downward and to make it upright you will need to apply the force perpendicular to the surface and if we divide the weight components into along the body and perpendicular to the body you will get perpendicular component as $5mg\cos{\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the body with horizontal when the body is lying on the ground the $\theta = 0°$ and as you make it upright the $\theta$ will increase to $90°$ thus the limits of integration are $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Hope it helps. ;)
Edit:
Sorry to inform you but I have no examples of average force as I haven't read it anywhere I only analysed this from the images you gave above.
Now for the integration process

> I don't understand on which point the weight is acting,is it on the center of mass or blocks

The weight is acting on the centre of mass of the system (tower) of blocks.
I will explain this easier way but if you want the harder way then inform here.
So to get the tower of 5 blocks upright you need to apply the force $F = mg\cos{\theta}$ as explained in the image you have provided. And to get total work done you need to get the sum of all the forces on every specific angle between $0$ to $90°$ and we will get this by integration. $$W_{\text{total}} = \int_0^{π/2}{5mg\cos{\theta}d\theta}$$ $$W_{\text{total}} = 5mg\int{\cos{\theta}d\theta} $$ and rest is solved in the image and still if you can't get it then use a integral calculator that shows steps.
Now for the reason we are dividing the integral with $π/2$ is because as stated before in my answer the definition of average force but here we will substitute angular displacement instead of linear displacement (height in method 1) thus you are moving the tower from 0 to $π/2$ thus the angular displacement will be $\pi/2$.
Hope you can understand now as this answer is getting too long. :)
Edit_2:

> Are we applying force only on the center of mass and not on any other point?

Yes you can apply the force on any other point but actually in calculating the work done we take the force taken by the body as example here we need the force $5mg\cos{\theta}$ to make the block upright, so if you are applying the force $F_t$ at a point $r$ units up from the pivot of the block (which is the point of contact of the block with the ground) then $$\text{Torque} = T = F_tr = 5mg\cos{\theta}$$ and now the force applied by you depends on the point where you apply but the force needed by the body is same i.e. $5mg\cos{\theta}$ so if you apply force very near to the pivot then $r$ will be small and you will need to apply more force ad if you apply the force farther from pivot you will need less force to obtain the same amount $5mg\cos{\theta}$ and I think this answers all the three questions you asked about the force.
Now for the second question:
In physics work done is a scalar quantity that is it doesn't have a direction because it is the dot product of two vectors Force and displacement this is the basic concept of the work done. So if work done is a scalar quantity then we don't need to worry about the force wether it is angular or linear (as I think) because we only need the magnitude of the force.
Edit_3:
The reason $5mg$ is here because it is the weight of the block. And the force applied by you exactly cancels the weight because you apply that much amount of force if you apply less amount of force then the block will not lift. To lift the block up you need to apply the force perpendicular to the surface of the block which is $5mg\cos{\theta}$ and that's the torque which we are applying $F_tr$. Also the point of contact from the ground is the point or surface which is on the ground.

Comment: Thanks a lot but could you illustrate some examples where the concept of average force is used(I want to apply it more in upcoming problems).As for example the concept of average displacement makes a lot of problems easy since we don't need to deal with integrations anymore.

Comment: Could you please describe more on the integration process?I don't understand on which point the weight is acting,is it on the center of mass or blocks?It would be quite feasible to me if you deduced the integration using infinitesimals $dx$.

Comment: Sorry I can't think of any method to solve this by using infinitesimals .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the troubles,a few requests:1)Are we applying force only on the center of mass and not on any other point?Why is it enough to apply force on center of mass instead of any other point?Furthermore the force given in figure is the weight and not force applied by us,but as you mentioned the force that is applied by us is in the work done.

Comment: Also since we are multiplying force with angular displacement,doesn't that mean we are actually calculating work done by torque?Since force is linear,we ought to consider linear displacement but here angular displacement has been used. Lastly,i actually didn't get how you took theta(angle).A picture will be very helpful.

Comment: I am extremely sorry if this answer is getting exceedingly long,but as i am still learning and a novice,i thought it is obligatory for me to fully grasp the concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot(!!!!) for taking the troubles,but i still have doubt on one issue,why is there $mg$ here whereas we ourselves are supposed to apply the force?Why is the force applied by us exactly cancel the weight?Also i didn't understand how $F_tr=mg\cos\theta$ and where point of contact with the ground is.Please forgive me if i am being too dumb.

Comment: If you understood correctly then please consider upvoting the answer.

Comment: Thank you!!A doubt:if we apply force exactly equal to $mg$,then according to newton's 1st law,the block will not move since net force is $0$. I mean consider the initial case when the block is in ground.Here the normal force is equal to $5mg$,so net force on the object in this case is $0$. Now we can apply any force,so why only $5mg$ in this case?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you are right but we take $5mg$ for the sake of simplicity as this is not a graduate level question.